# Finding "related posts" in a database

Tags: sql

So quick question: I'm working on adding "related posts" for my site, using my own custom CMS I built. Right now I'm trying to have it done in a single SQL query, where it would return the 3 top results. I don't use tags btw. This is what I came up with so far, and it's doing a decent result, but I'd like to somehow prioritize keywords that appear in titles versus descriptions. Anyone can think of a better way?

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE title LIKE "%keyword1%" OR title LIKE "%keyword2%" OR description LIKE "%keyword1%" OR description LIKE "%keyword2%" LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the "case"

```
SELECT *, case WHEN title like '%keyword1%' or title like  '%keyword2%' THEN 1
  ELSE 0 END as Priority
 FROM db WHERE title LIKE '%keyword1%' OR title LIKE '%keyword2%' OR description LIKE '%keyword1%' OR description LIKE '%keyword2%' LIMIT 3 Order by Priority desc
```

so if title contains keyword set `Priority` to 1, otherwise set to 0 and then order it by `Priority`

Answer (score 0):

UNION together two internal SELECTs, one for the keyword matches and one for the description matches.  In each of those internal SELECTs, assign a new `priority` column with value 1 for the keyword SELECT and 2 for the description SELECT.

Then, from the UNIONed results, SELECT the top 3 ORDER BY `priority`.

I'd give an example for your database / data except that you didn't give much of a hint about what database you're using, or about what your data looks like.

Comment: It's SQLite and each entry is a post.. with title, description, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prioritize, you could assign some weight to each LIKE match.  Something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM
(
  SELECT *, 1 'Weight' FROM db WHERE title LIKE '%keyword1' OR title LIKE '%keyword2'
  UNION 
  SELECT *, 2 'Weight' FROM db WHERE description LIKE '%keyword1' OR description LIKE '%keyword2'
)T1
ORDER BY Weight ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Oracle DB, then you can use [Oracle Text](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14217/overview.htm#i1007403) queries to do this sort of thing very efficiently. It'll let you rank results based on relatedness to keywords.